# Debugging SP on SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I have a stored procedure that I execute through SSIS using an execute sql task. It appears to work on SISS, but when I look at the database the record is not created. The connection is for the correct database. The PROBLEM.

I have put a breakpoint ON and checked all the variables getting fed IN AND THEN ran it manually IN SQL SERVER management.

The SP work perfectly in SSMS with the same input parameters, but when executed through SSIS, it does not create the records required and does not give any error out.

In the SP I have a try catch to put any erorrs in the stored procedure when it erorr out to a table, but there is no entry for the SSIS run. According to the Error table for the SP and SSIS it looks like it executed successfully. When I go to see if the record it is not created. I cannot see the problem. Is there something I can put into the stored procedure to debug this problem or anything further I can do in SSIS to work this out ?

It has been 3 hours on this problem so looking for a fresh perspective to work out what is happening.

The SSIS package definitely points to the correct database and stored procedure.

From the watch window it appears to be giving all the parameters the correct values and does not error in SSIS.

Comment: Add logging internal to your SP?

Comment: If you have access to the server, turn on profiler and see what is actually happening. There is nothing within SSIS that will cause the stored procedure to behave differently than executed from within SSMS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked it out with sql profiler . In the Target database there is sequence that is incremented each time a new record needs to be created . When I deleted the record to rerun it it created it with a different ID number , I was expecting it to be created with the same ID number.

Thanks Billinkc !